# Retrieving information from RFID card using Ardunio

Tags: c++, arduino, rfid

I'm working on RFID attendance management system using Arduino.
I'm saving the data on the second block on Arduino. The only data I'm saving is  "1".

Here's my code:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);        
    SPI.begin();               
}

int block=2;

byte blockcontent[16] = {"1"};
//byte blockcontent[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
byte readbackblock[18];

void loop()
{       
    mfrc522.PCD_Init(); 
    for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
    }

    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;
    }

    Serial.println("card selected");         
    writeBlock(block, blockcontent);
    readBlock(block, readbackblock);
    Serial.print("read block: ");
    for (int j=0 ; j<16 ; j++)
    {
        Serial.write (readbackblock[j]);
        if(readbackblock[j]=="1"){
            Serial.print("Test completed!!");
        }
    }
    Serial.println("");        
}
```

**My Issue:**

I wanted to retrieve the data from the Arduino and do something with it. I know that by using Serial.write (`readbackblock[j]`) we transmits the ASCII numbers as human-readable characters to the serial monitor ( and I get "1" on the Serial Monitor) but the following if statement is not working.

```
if(readbackblock[j]=="1"){
    Serial.print("Test completed!!");
}
```

Comment: `blockcontent` is a byte array, `readbackblock[j]` is a single byte and `"1"` is a string (a nul terminated char array). You can't compare those with `==`.

Comment: @gre_gor what should I do?

Comment: @ahsan you should learn about data types. And you should post minimal, but complete code

Comment: ok I will but how can I retrieve the information from an RDIF card can someone please tell me that